# How to add a data using djongo which do not have any model defined in djongo

Tags: django-models, django-rest-framework, djongo

I have a json which is not based on any django model but want to store it in mongodb using Djongo.
Structure of json is as follow:
{
name:"test",
desc:{
    type:1,
    tags:[2,4,5,5]
},
test:["asd","asda"],
perform:True
}

Comment: How would you like to add data to your database? via post method?

Comment: It can be done via post or by script

Comment: But why don't you have a Django model for it? What you have been trying, it seems like an anti-pattern design.